# Open new device descriptor with same options as reference descriptor

Tags: c, linux

I have an open device descriptor, where I don't know the device name and the options 
passed to open(...).
I want to open a new device descriptor with the same options passed to open.

```
int newFd = copy(referenceFd);
```

Where copy would do the job. dup() is certainly the wrong choice as a further ioctl() on newFd would also alter the referenceFd, therefore I want to open a new descriptor.

Is there a system call which provides such functionality?
I have not been able to find something yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get the descriptor flags of file descriptor `fd` using

```
    int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
```

Then, reopen the descriptor using the Linux-specific `/proc/self/fd/`*`fd`* entry:

```
    int  newfd;
    char buffer[32];

    if (snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "/proc/self/fd/%d", fd) < sizeof buffer) {
        do {
            newfd = open(buffer, flags & ~(O_TRUNC | O_EXCL), 0666);
        } while (newfd == -1 && errno == EINTR);
        if (newfd == -1) {
            /* Error: Cannot reopen file. Error in errno. */
        }
    } else {
        /* Error: the path does not fit in the buffer. */
    }
```

The reopened file descriptor is then in `newfd`.

Note that you most likely want to make sure `O_TRUNC` (truncate the file) and `O_EXCL` (fail if exists) are not in the flags, to avoid the cases where reopening using the exact original flags would cause unwanted results.

You do **not** want to use `lstat()`, because that opens up a race condition with respect to rename -- a user renaming the target file between the `lstat()` and the `open()` in above code. The above avoids that completely.

If you don't want to be Linux-specific, add code that tries the same with `/dev/fd/`*`fd`* if the above fails. It is supported in some Unix systems (and most Linux distros too).

Answer (score 3):

You can probably do it with a series of [`fcntl` calls](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html):

> `F_GETFD` - Get the file descriptor flags defined in  that are associated with the file descriptor fildes.
>
> `F_GETFL` - Get the file status flags and file access modes, defined in , for the file description associated with fildes.

I linked the SUSv4 page above; you might also be interested in [the Linux version](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fcntl.2.html).

Comment: It seems that in F_GETFD the device name is not stored? Otherwise how can I open the device a second time so I can set the flags with fcntl?

Comment: @the_summer: If you don't mind messing with Linux specifics, you can `lstat` the fd in `/proc/self/fd`, that should get you the device name